# AWS CLI NetworkInterfaces Tags

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, tags, command-line-interface, network-interface

I have trying to Tag all my Network Interfaces but I need to tag them according the the Tag that they Instaces or ELBs that are attached to each Network Interface.
Is there a script or way that I tag the NI according to the Tag of the instance or ELB attached to it?
Any help or advice on what will be the best way to do it from CLI will be appreciated due that I can't do it manually, I'm having more than 400 NIs 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

AWS has commandline interfaces.  They have docs at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/index.html

A search for add-tag or add-tags would get you moving in the right direction.  I haven't touched them much.  I just know they exist, so scripting things might be easier that way.